# setting up google play expansion file library in android studio

Tags: android-studio, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to use apk expansion files in my android project, I've read this 
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html
I tried to follow those steps, but I cannot figure out how to set up `/ include` in my project / google play apk expansion library. 
I've been searching for hours, didn't find right answer. Any help?

Comment: show what you have done here, any codes?

Answer (score 5):

I just tried to set up the modules listed in http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html today, but the `play_apk_expansion/downloader_library` cannot be imported as supplied.

The issue is a stale library reference in `play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/project.properties`

Update the last line from:

`android.library.reference.1=../market_licensing`

to:

`android.library.reference.1=../../play_licensing/library`

**Note the extra ../**

Then use `File -> New -> Import Module...` to import the `play_apk_expansion/downloader_library` as usual. It will also import the `play_licensing/library` as `library` but that can be renamed to something more useful afterwards.

Comment: you can also comment this line **android.library.reference.1=../../play_licensing/library** if you're using gradle. Then add the dependency in gradle instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a better way than importing via eclipse, so I have set up a github repo where this has already been done:

https://github.com/coltsoftware/ExpansionAPKsAndroidStudio

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy sdk/extras/google/play_licening/library to Eclipse workspace
2. Copy sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library to Eclipse workspace
3. Eclipse: New --> Android project from sources to create two library projects from the above copied files. Don't forget to make the correct library reference to play_licening for downloader_library.
4. Android Studio: New --> Import Module, and import play_licening first, and then downloader_library.

Answer (score 1):

To use [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33360373/1677912) with Android Studio 2.1, I needed to update:

```
market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/project.properties
```

to

```
android.library.reference.1=../../market_licensing/library
```

before I could import the module as described.

Comment: Tip: Referring to other answers by "above" and "below" is meaningless, as the display order is changeable. If you're going to post an answer, post an answer. If it really is a comment, get the rep and comment. (You could get 10 rep with about 15 minute's effort, so no excuses!)