# How to add Google Play APK Expansion Library to android studio project?

Tags: android-studio

I have so apps that use APK Expansion Files.  I usually have build these apps with `ant`.  But I want to add AdMob code to these apps and apparently there is no way to build an AdMob app from the command-line so I have to use Android Studio.  I looked at these docs: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html and they do not tell me what magic incantation I need to use in my gradle file.  Does anyone know?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368251/how-to-make-android-expansion-file-using-android-studio                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891204/setting-up-google-play-expansion-file-library-in-android-studio

Comment: Hmmm those answers do not seem to apply to Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to use APK Expansion Files if you are using Android Studio. (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173235) That kind of sucks.  So I guess I go back to using Eclipse.